# Fortran HDF5: Compile time switching between H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE and H5T_NATIVE_FLOAT

Tags: floating-point, fortran, hdf5

I tried searching for an answer to this problem I'm encountering, but I was not able to find an answer (or if this is possible, for that matter).

I work on two computational fluid dynamics solvers, both written in Fortran.
These two solvers share the source files that handle data I/O.
The main difference is that one solver utilizes double precision reals (real8) whereas the other utilizes single precision (real4).

For the initial HDF5 development, I implemented the HDF5 I/O in the double precision solver. Everything works as intended, no problems there. The HDF5 examples provided in the repository were more than enough to guide me.

Now I want to also utilize these HDF5 I/O routines in the single precision solver.
However, writing real numbers poses a problem, since I need to define H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE or H5T_NATIVE_FLOAT in the HDF5 API calls.

What I want is to be able to switch between H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE or H5T_NATIVE_FLOAT in compile time, based on the compiled solver.

Since there are more than 60 calls to the HDF5 API, using Makefile directives is not an elegant solution.

How would I go about accomplishing this?

Since H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE and H5T_NATIVE_FLOAT are both HDF5 types, I wasn't able to find anything else that works. Perhaps I can define a symbolic type that inherits the double or float type from the HDF5 types?

I haven't faced anything quite like this problem and I don't know what a good approach would be.

Comment: It could be helpful to show examples of code. Something like `use hd5f, my_data_type=>h5t_native_float` could work in some cases but not others.

Comment: Surely there must be some mechanism to use multiple datatypes  (e.g. the IEEE fpe types) in a single data file directly, without using some system specific native_float. But I do not use HDF.

Comment: It's a while since I used HDF5 so I'm not sure how much effort these suggestions might be, and they don't answer the question so much as go round it entirely.  (1) store all f-p numbers in double precision, the single-precision version of the code would have to cast numbers up and down as appropriate (2) design the files with provisions for storing both single- and double-precision floats; the solvers use the precision they want.  And some process I wave airily into existence takes care that, if a file holds both versions they tell the same story.

Comment: I probably misunderstood your problem. For my stuff I use Mark's suggestion n. 1, albeit in a different file format. And for one code only. No matter which precision I use to compile it, it will always store the output in the same precision. In my opinion, computational codes should be able to be compiled for computation in either precision (end even quad, if possible).

Answer (score 1):

The HDF5 Fortran library provides the `h5kind_to_type` helper (documented in the "Library General (H5)" section of the reference manual), that helps you parameterise your code for different data types.  See below for an example.

(The in-file representation of your results does not need to match the in-memory representation.)

```
PROGRAM HDF5Kind
  IMPLICIT NONE
  
  ! Pick your kind for calculations.
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: calc_rk = KIND(1.0)
  
  ! Pick your kind for storing results.  Maybe it is the same as 
  ! `calc_rk`, maybe not.  See also comments for file_type_id below 
  ! - maybe the in-file representation doesn't correspond to any Fortran 
  ! compiler kind.
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: store_rk = calc_rk   ! or KIND(1.0D0) or whatever
  
  CHARACTER(*), PARAMETER :: hdf5_output_file_name  &
      = 'HDF5Kind.h5'
  
  CALL do_a_model_run
CONTAINS
  SUBROUTINE do_a_model_run
    ! Calculation results.
    REAL(calc_rk) :: my_results(10)
    
    CALL do_some_calcs(my_results)
    CALL write_some_data(my_results)
  END SUBROUTINE do_a_model_run
  
  SUBROUTINE do_some_calcs(my_results)
    REAL(calc_rk), INTENT(OUT) :: my_results(:)
    INTEGER :: i      ! my_results array index.
    
    DO i = 1, SIZE(my_results)
      my_results(i) = REAL(i, calc_rk)  &
          / REAL(SIZE(my_results), calc_rk)
    END DO
  END SUBROUTINE do_some_calcs
  
  SUBROUTINE write_some_data(my_results)
    USE HDF5
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_LOC
    
    ! The results to be written.
    REAL(calc_rk), INTENT(IN), TARGET :: my_results(:)
    
    INTEGER :: h5err                  ! HDF5 API error code.
    INTEGER(HID_T) :: file_id         ! HDF5 file identifier.
    INTEGER(HID_T) :: space_id        ! ID for dataspace matching `my_results`.
    INTEGER(HID_T) :: file_type_id    ! In file type identfier.
    INTEGER(HID_T) :: set_id          ! Dataset identifier.
    INTEGER(HID_T) :: mem_type_id     ! In memory (`my_results`) type identifier.
    
    CALL H5open_f(h5err)
    IF (h5err /= 0) ERROR STOP 'Uh oh - H5open_f blew up.'
    
    CALL H5Fcreate_f(  &
        NAME=         hdf5_output_file_name,  &
        ACCESS_FLAGS= H5F_ACC_TRUNC_F,  &
        FILE_ID=      file_id,  &
        HDFERR=       h5err )
    IF (h5err /= 0) ERROR STOP 'Dang - H5Fcreate_f did not perform.'
    
    CALL H5Screate_simple_f(  &
        RANK=         RANK(my_results),  &
        DIMS=         SHAPE(my_results, HSIZE_T),  &
        SPACE_ID=     space_id,  &
        HDFERR=       h5err )
    IF (h5err /= 0) ERROR STOP 'Nooo - H5Screate_simple_f let me down.'
    
    ! file_type_id doesn't have to correspond to a Fortran kind supported by 
    ! the compiler - e.g. you could store little-endian numbers on a machine 
    ! that works with a big-endian representation.
    file_type_id = h5kind_to_type(store_rk, H5_REAL_KIND)
    CALL H5Dcreate_f(  &
        LOC_ID=       file_id,  &
        NAME=         'my_results',  &
        TYPE_ID=      file_type_id,  &
        SPACE_ID=     space_id,  &
        DSET_ID=      set_id,  &
        HDFERR=       h5err )
    IF (h5err /= 0) ERROR STOP 'Awww - H5Dcreate_f didn''t.'
    
    mem_type_id = h5kind_to_type(KIND(my_results), H5_REAL_KIND)
    CALL H5Dwrite_f(  &
        DSET_ID=      set_id,  &
        MEM_TYPE_ID=  mem_type_id,  &
        BUF=          C_LOC(my_results),  &
        HDFERR=       h5err )
    IF (h5err /= 0) ERROR STOP 'Ouch - H5Dwrite_f quit in disgust.'
    
    CALL H5Sclose_f(  &
        SPACE_ID=     space_id,  &
        HDFERR=       h5err )
    IF (h5err /= 0) ERROR STOP 'Ooof - H5Sclose_f gave up the ghost.'
    
    CALL H5Dclose_f(  &
        DSET_ID=      set_id,  &
        HDFERR=       h5err )
    IF (h5err /= 0) ERROR STOP 'Huh - H5Dclose_f went AWOL.'
    
    CALL H5Fclose_f(  &
        FILE_ID=      file_id,  &
        HDFERR=       h5err )
    IF (h5err /= 0) ERROR STOP 'Gasp - H5Fclose_f failed to finish.'
    
    CALL H5close_f(h5err)
    IF (h5err /= 0)  &
        ERROR STOP 'Let''s be honest... no one bothers with H5close_f.'
  END SUBROUTINE write_some_data
END PROGRAM HDF5Kind
```

Comment: Your example is higher level and more sophisticated, but overall I think that it is the most general and elegant approach. The quick solution provided by @Ross more than does the trick for now. However, I will keep your answer bookmarked for cases that I want to restart a simulation for the double precision solver using results written by the single precision solver. For those cases, just renaming the types will not work. I need something more general and I think your answer provides that.

Comment: This is a good elegant approach

Answer (score 0):

I recommend defining an intermediate value that switches between `H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE` and `H5T_NATIVE_FLOAT`. All (60+) calls to the hdf5 api would use this variable, and its value would switch based on a preprocessor flag.

For example, if you are `include`-ing an hdf5 header file (untested):

```
#ifdef solver_is_single_precision
#   define MY_HDF5_REAL_TYPE H5T_NATIVE_FLOAT
#else
#   defile MY_HDF5_REAL_TYPE H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE
#endif
```

Or if you are using an hdf5 module (again, untested, and I don't know the names for the types inside the module off-hand):

```
   use hdf5, only : &
#ifdef solver_is_single_precision
      my_hdf5_real_type => native_float
#else
      my_hdf5_real_type => native_double
#endif
```

Ideally this would go in some code-specific hdf5 header or module file, but it could also go at the top of each relevant routine or module.

Also note that that hdf5 routines exist to convert types, such as `h5kind_to_type` (https://docs.hdfgroup.org/archive/support/HDF5/doc/fortran/NewFeatures_F2003.pdf), although I have never used them.

Comment: Well, actually I think this works and is fairly simple! I do use the hdf5 module, thus I tried your second suggestion. It was as simple as that, never thought it'd be that simple... Funny thing is I rename module variables for local use on many occasions, but I never thought I could do the same thing with variable types. :)